# Composition vs. Inheritance dependency injection

Tags: php, language-agnostic

I have a Parser with three classes of objects: the parser itself, `Token`s, and `State`s.  The Parser generates tokens from the lexer.  Everything is black boxed, so the tokens know nothing about the parser state or the parser, and the state knows nothing of the tokens.  A fairly simple version of the arrangement:

```
class Parser {
   public function parse() {
      $this->state = new StEmpty;
      while ($token = $this->lexer->get()) {
         $this->state = $this->token->expect($this);
      }
   }
   public function stateStart() {
      return $this->state->stateStart();
   }
}
class StartToken {
   public function expect(Parser $parser) {
      return $parser->stateStart();
   }
}
class StEmpty {
   public function stateStart() {
      return new StStart;
   }
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that sometimes when a state changes, the parser needs to take some action (such as add a rule to the tree when the ending-rule token is reached).  Only the `State` knows that, so it is up to the state to tell the parser what to do.  Problem is getting the `Parser` to the `State`.  I could inject the `Parser` in the state constructor, but not every `State` needs the parser, and that would lead to a lot of duplicate code (unless I had a base class for the `State`s and the `Parser` was a protected member, but I want to avoid extending anything).  I could also inject the `Parser` in the `state` methods that need it, but I have a similar problem: that would be a lot of duplication, and not all of the `State` implementations would need the parser for given methods.

So my question is how can I get the `State` to know about the `Parser` when it needs to without unnecessary inheritance or code duplication?  If I need another class that's perfectly acceptable.

---

In case this is difficult to follow, here is an "unraveled" version:

```
class Parser {
   public function parse() {
      $this->state = 'StEmpty';

      while ($token = $this->lexer->get()) {
         switch ($token) {
            case 'StartToken':
               switch ($this->state) {
                  case 'StEmpty':
                     $this->state = 'StStart';
                     break;
               }
               break;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The answer to this question could apply to other languages as well, but I know this would be easier to do in languages that allow overloading.  PHP does not.

Comment: Can you explain why you "want to avoid extending anything."  That seems like a very odd thing to say with respect to OO code.

Comment: @drrcknlsn there is a small (I think) vanguard of people that hate inheritance so much they never want to use it and favor composition in all instances.  I will relent if it's necessary, but keep in mind that not all states need access to the parser anyway, so this may not even be appropriate.

Comment: I've never heard of such a thing.  One of the main benefits of OO design is inheritance.  As for children needing access or not, that's where multiple levels of inheritance come into play.  Those that need access would extend a class that has the injected Parser (which itself would extend the base class).  Those that don't need access would just extend the base class.  You can also solve this with composition if you want, but meh...

Comment: @drrcknlsn the `Parser` can't and shouldn't know when to inject and when not to inject.  This means it will attempt an injection at inappropriate times (not that it matters .. unused arguments are ignored).  The problem with extending separate classes is if you have to change one to use the parser, so I think in this case it would be preferable to always have access, though still not ideal.

Comment: Of course the `Parser` can and should know when to inject.  If it's instantiating the child class that requires it, then inject; otherwise, don't.  And it knows which child class to instantiate based on what state it's currently in.  And if it doesn't know what state it's currently in, then you have a dysfunctional parser. :-P

Comment: The Parser doesn't instantiate the state object, the token does.  The parser "knows" where it is transparently .. I could easily do an `if state == whatever` check but that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Tokens shouldn't be telling a parser what its state is.  I'm no compiler programmer, but I do know that when you run into situations where one class needs to know about the state of another class, it's a good time to reevaluate your design, as that's breaking encapsulation.

Comment: You have to remember that object instances and class definitions are totally abstract.  The *Parser* in concept knows its state and evaluates tokens to update state and emit output.  The `Parser` object is very dumb in that regard.  The `Token`s don't directly tell the parser what state its in, they tell the parser what move to make, the parser tells its state about that move, and the state informs the parser of the state that results from the move.

Comment: `Token` shouldn't be telling `Parser` what move to make, was my point.  To be honest, I don't see any reason for `Token` to even know of the existence of `Parser`, and certainly shouldn't be creating state objects for it.  `Parser` should create its *own* state objects based on feedback from the `Token`s.  The `Parser` shouldn't be dumb - it's what's solving the problem (i.e. parsing).  The `Token`s should be dumb.  They're just there to model the data that `Parser` needs to know about to make its decisions.  At least, that's how the parsers that I've ever looked at behaved.

Comment: The `Token`s are *very* dumb .. the `Parser` is not as dumb.  The Tokens only tell the parser what move to make indirectly.  Your suggestion that "the Parser should create its own state objects ..." is reminiscent of *asking*, which is always a bad move in OOP.  The Tokens *tell* the Parser what to expect.  The Parser ends up changing its own state in the end, but from information it is told rather than information that it gathers and evaluates.

Comment: I see what you're saying with respect to TDA, but if `Token` needs to know about `Parser` to decide which state create, that's also violating TDA.  Having `Parser` make the decision is the lesser of two evils, IMO.  In any case, I don't think I'm going to be of any help, since I know nothing but elevator pitch design details about your project.  Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 5.4 introduces traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Perhaps you could use traits as a halfway between inheritance and injection.

Comment: Traits would be awesome .. if only I *could* use PHP 5.4